# Can I switch from glDrawArrays to using Vertex Buffer Objects?

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es, vbo

I have an OpenGL 1.1 ES 2D sprite engine that's based on one GL_TRIANGLE_FAN per sprite.  The main rendering code that gets called per-sprite, per-frame is as follows:

```
void drawTexture(BitmapImage* aImage, short* vertices, float* texCoords,
            ColorMap &colorMap, TInt xDest, TInt yDest, TInt aAlpha)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_SHORT, 0, vertices);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords);
    glColorPointer(RGBA_BYTES, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, colorMap.GetMap());

    TFloat scaleX, scaleY;
    aImage->getScale(scaleX, scaleY);
    glTranslatef((float)xDest, (float)yDest, 0.0f);
    glScalef(scaleX, scaleY, 1.0f);
    glRotatef(aImage->getRotAngle(), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

I've been told that switching to Vertex Buffer Objects (VBOs) will significantly increase the performance of rendering, so I'd like to do that. My research thus far has lead me to several examples showing how to set up individual vertex, color, and texture offset buffers, but good examples of how to interleave this data have been more elusive.

For example, I'm pretty sure this is how I'd set up to render with my vertex data in a VBO:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &batchBufferHandle);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, batchBufferHandle);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataSize, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertextPointer(3, GL_SHORT, 0, 0);
glDrawElements(..., 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &batchBufferHandle);
```

Apparently I'd generate and bind similar buffers for texture coordinates and vertex color data, though I'm not 100% clear on how setting those up would differ.

My understanding is that the speed boost would come from rendering a bunch of these triangle fans in one "draw call", but what is a "draw call" in this context?  DrawElements() gets called multiple times using this methodology, so that can't be it...?

Whatever the case, it would mean that I'd have to generate a VBO (or three) that contain all the data in series for a bunch of sprites. That can be difficult enough on its own given the legacy code I'm dealing with, but I also need to translate, scale, and rotate each individual sprite.  Where does that data go in the VBO(s)?

My conclusion thus far is using VBOs is only helpful in the case of a SINGLE, but complex object. It would appear what I want to do is not possible -- provide OpenGL with a list of sprites to render (including all vertex, color, texture map, scale, rotation, and translation information for each).

Is my assessment correct or is there a way to do this (using OpenGL ES 1.1)?

Comment: `glDrawElements` is a draw call, because it draws something. To apply transforms to vertices, use matrices. VBOs are unlikely to help much in a sprite based game, since there's so little geometry to render anyway.

Comment: Doing that would allow me to put everything in VBOs but then would I even notice a difference, given there's so little geometry?  I think my bottlenecks are fill rate and the fact that everything has per-pixel alpha.  What's really hitting hard in this particular case is bitmapped fonts.  Screens with a lot of text on them scroll very slowly, which is why I was looking at this specifically for drawing text.  But another option is to pre-render the text into a texture then just manipulate that texture (because the text doesn't change).